# Equations not displaying correctly

Tags: math

How do I get the equations in this link to display correctly?  Currently they just appear as `$$some_maths_text$$` in all browsers.

http://newsroom.uber.com/2014/09/inferring-uber-rider-destinations/

Thanks.

Comment: [Math in HTML (and CSS)](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/math/)

Answer (score 1):

Try getting [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). This is a JavaScript library which can render mathematical equations. Most browsers need some add on libraries to display mathematics and mathjax is the most popular method at the moment. Other method include making static images or using MathML which only works well in Firefox.

Comment: Just looked a KaTeX. There is quite a lot it does not support `\mathbf`, `\operatorname` being the two biggest missing things. It might be an option  if you want a fast light version of tex, rather than a pretty much complete LaTeX implementation.